# the solution of $\lambda u''(x) = u(x)$ is $u(x)=\{sin(n\pi x)\}_{n=1}^\infty$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

in my text it says: the solution of $\lambda u''(x) = u(x)$ is $u(x)=\{sin(n\pi x)\}_{n=1}^\infty$with boundary condition u(0)=u(1)=0

how do I know that this set contains all solutions? What if their is some weird function satisfying this equation.

Comment: where is $\lambda$?

Comment: The general theory of higher order linear differential equations tells you how every solution of $\lambda u''(x) = u(x)$ with fixed $\lambda$ should look alike: it's always $C_1 \cos{\frac{x}{\sqrt{\lambda}}} + C_2 \sin{\frac{x}{\sqrt{\lambda}}}$ and nothing else.

Comment: @Leox Non-trivial solution of BVP for this equation can exist only for certain values of $\lambda$. So, these values are just already substituted.

Comment: Also, we need to know something about sign of $\lambda$. Or everything that's written in OP's post and in my comment is questionable.

Comment: how is sign of $\lambda$  relevant? @Evgeny

Comment: Sign of $\lambda$ determines roots of characteristic equation for this ODE. The characteristic equation for $\lambda u'' = u$ is $\lambda z^2 -1 = 0$, so depending on sign of $\lambda$ it may have two complex roots or two real roots of different signs. However, the latter case doesn't have non-trivial solutions to BVP (as far as I remember), so without loss of generality we can suppose that $\lambda < 0 $.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just want to extend what I've written in comments.

I assume that you know how to solve higher order linear differential equations and how general solution could be written depending on associated characteristic equation. If you don't, please read [this](https://www.math.wisc.edu/~angenent/320.2011s/somewronskians.pdf), for example.

Returning back to your question.
Suppose that $\lambda$ is real. We want to solve the BVP $u(0)=u(1)=0$ for equation $\lambda u'' = u$.
There could be three possibilities: $\lambda > 0$, $\lambda = 0$ and $\lambda < 0$.

- Case $\lambda = 0$ is very trivial: equation transforms to $u \equiv 0$ and it is not interesting at all.
- If $\lambda > 0$ then general solution could be written as $u(x) = C_1 \cdot \exp{\frac{x}{\sqrt{\lambda}}} + C_2 \cdot \exp{\left (-\frac{x}{\sqrt{\lambda}} \right)}$. Let's show that in this case there's only trivial solution (i.e. $u(x) \equiv 0$) to our BVP. BVP generates system of homogeneous linear equations with matrix
  \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1 \\
  \exp{\frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}}} & \exp{\left ( -\frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}} \right )}
  \end{pmatrix}
  The determinant of this matrix is $2 \sinh{\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}}\right)}$ and it's never zero, so there is only a trivial solution to this system $\Rightarrow$ $C_1 = C_2 = 0$ and only $u(x)\equiv 0$ satisfies BVP.
- The last case is $\lambda < 0$. The general solution could be written as $u(x) = C_1 \cos{\frac{x}{\sqrt{\lambda}}} + C_2 \sin{\frac{x}{\sqrt{\lambda}}}$. Let's solve BVP. Plugging $x = 0$ gives $C_1 = 0$ and plugging $x=1$ gives $C_2 \sin \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}} = 0$. Since we are trying to find non-trivial solution, $C_2 \neq 0$ and we came to equation $\sin \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}} = 0$. From it we obtain that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}} = \pi n, \; n \in \mathbb{N}$.

The final conclusion is that this BVP could be solved only for specific values of $\lambda$, namely for those which satisfy $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}} = \pi n$ for some integer $n$. The only functions that are solutions of this BVP are those of form $C \sin  n \pi x$.